# D3 not updating label

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map and a matching legend on my website. As the user selects different values from a select list, the map is updated and in the same function, the legend should be updated with new values. As the map actualization works properly, the values of the legend stay the same even in the console are logged the right values if I log the variables.

This is the function that draws the legend:

```
color_domain = [wert1, wert2, wert3, wert4, wert5];
ext_color_domain = [0, wert1, wert2, wert3, wert4, wert5];
console.log(ext_color_domain);
legend_labels = ["< "+wert1, ""+wert1, ""+wert2, ""+wert3, ""+wert4, "> "+wert5];
color = d3.scale.threshold()
 .domain(color_domain)
 .range(["#85db46", "#ffe800", "#ffba00", "#ff7d73", "#ff4e40", "#ff1300"]);

var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

  var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

  legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.7);

  legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
  .text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });
  console.log(legend_labels); //gives the right legend_labels but doesn't display them correctly

};
```

Sadly even the map is updated with new colors they're colored with the old thresholds. This is the way the map is colored:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "id")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.immoscout).features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(rateById[d.id]); 
  })
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This is tough to answer without a complete, working code sample but...

You are not handling the enter, update, exit pattern correctly.  You never really *update* existing elements, you are only re-binding data and entering new ones.

Say you've called your legend function once already, now you have new data and you do:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");
```

This re-binds the data and computes an `enter` selection.  It says, hey d3, what data elements are new?  For those new ones, you then append a `g`.  Further:

```
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.7);
```

Again, this is operating on those newly entered elements **only**.  The ones that already existed on the page aren't touched at all.

Untested code, but hopefully it points you in the right direction:

```
// selection of all enter, update, exit
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
  .data(ext_color_domain); //<-- a key function would be awesome here

legend.exit().remove();  //<-- did the data go away?  remove the g bound to it

// ok, what data is coming in?  create new elements;
var legendEnter = legend.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");
legendEnter.append("rect");
legendEnter.append("text");

// ok, now handle our updates...
legend.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
  .attr("width", ls_w)
  .attr("height", ls_h)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d); })
  .style("opacity", 0.7);

legend.selectall("text")
  ...
```

There's some [really](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) [great](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) tutorials on this; and it's confusing as hell, but it's the foundation of  `d3`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your code and it only draws one rect of the legend. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @maidi, if you create a working jsFiddle or plunkr, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

An example that helps you get started with updating d3 (d3, v4):

```
const line = svg.selectAll('line').data(d3Data); // binds things
line.exit().remove(); // removes old data

line.enter()
  .append('line') // add new lines for new items on enter
  .merge(line) // <--- this will make the updates to the lines
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'red');
```